# regEx works in notepad++ but not in python

Tags: python, regex

let's say we have this:

```
.................
=== Operation 'abcd::ddca:dsd' ended in 1.234s   /1.234s (100.00%) execution time
................
```

Using notepad++, I am able to identify this with:

```
^\=* Operation '([\d\D]*)' ended in (\d*.\d*)s\s*/(\d*.\d*)s \([\d\D]*\) execution time
```

I want the operation name and execution times to be grouped.

In python, trying this:

```
exp=re.compile(r"^\=* Operation \'([\d\D]*)\' ended in (\d*.\d*)s\s*/(\d*.\d*)s \([\d\D]*\) execution time")
```

provides nothing. 
I've tried `\\(` for escaping the literal paranthesis but it didn't work. I'm guessing I don't need to do that since I'm using r"[exp]" when building the object expression.

Any ideas on how to get the same result as in notepad++?

**LE: tried only with:**

```
exp=re.compile(r"^\=* Operation \'([\d\D]*)\'", flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

still doesn't find anything.

**LE2:**

later in the code I'm using `groups=exp.match(INPUT)`
and I get the pairs with `groups.group(n)`

ANSWER:
the problem was `match`. Using `search` **fixed the problem**

Comment: You need to escape the dots also.And IMO [\d\D] this would match all characters

Comment: Why are you using `[\d\D]`? That matches everything.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal the dots were not the problem, I have tried only getting the operation and I have no success. I'm not good with regEx, so I was hoping you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are those dots in your file actually part of the input?

Comment: Are you actually using the `search` method later in the code? `compile` only compiles the regular expression, and does not actually match the pattern. Can you please add the complete code.

Comment: updated question. This is not the first expression I'm using in the code, so I have used the same approach and had results with it. I guess it's just bad translation from my part when switching from what I have in Notepad++ to python code.

Comment: `match` is the problem here. You should use `re.search` to search complete string. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @SunnyNanda that was it.

Comment: same problem, that helped me to solve my issue: https://regex101.com/ (check the python flavor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression mentioned in the question is working for me without any change.

```
>>> s = """
... .................
... === Operation 'abcd::ddca:dsd' ended in 1.234s   /1.234s (100.00%) execution time
... ................
... """
>>> import re
>>> exp = re.compile(r"^\=* Operation \'([\d\D]*)\' ended in (\d*.\d*)s\s*/(\d*.\d*)s \([\d\D]*\) execution time", flags=re.M)
>>> re.search(exp, s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1038766b8>
>>> re.findall(exp, s)
[('abcd::ddca:dsd', '1.234', '1.234')]
```

Two things to consider though:

1. Use `re.M` in the flags argument
2. User `search` or `findall` method to do the matching. Make sure you are not using `re.match` because it will match only the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have double quotes at the end of the abcd::ddca:dsd

So :

```
exp=re.compile(r"^\=* Operation '([\d\D]*)\" ended in (\d*\.\d*)s\s*/(\d*\.\d*)s \([\d\D]*\) execution time", flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the `^` to match the start of a *line*, not just the start of the entire *string*:

```
exp=re.compile(r"^\=* Operation '([\d\D]*)' ended in (\d*\.\d*)s\s*/(\d*\.\d*)s \([\d\D]*\) execution time", flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I am not a regex guru, but this worked for me.

```
>>> i
"=== Operation 'abcd::ddca:dsd' ended in 1.234s   /1.234s (100.00%) execution time"
>>> exp = re.compile(r'^={3} Operation (.*?) ended in (\d+\.\d+s)(?:.*?)$')
>>> re.findall(exp,i)
[("'abcd::ddca:dsd'", '1.234s')]
```